# chmod permission set doesn't work in dockerfile

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm using php-fpm image from docker.

```
FROM php-fpm7.2

COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www && chmod u+x /var/start.sh

RUN find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;    
RUN find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

This is my dockerfile, but when I build it, permissions are still set as it was. root-root and not www-data. also 644 and 755 not happening. Why is that?

Comment: How are you running it?  How can you tell the permissions haven't changed?

Comment: ls -l gives me the same permission.